# Count Number of Prime Numbers up to a Given Number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to create a function to count the number of prime numbers up till a given number. However, I think I have some issues with the logic of my code as I'm currently not getting back the right number of prime numbers. Could anyone help me identify what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

```
def count_primes(num):
    ctr = 0

    for i in range(num+1):
        for x in range(2,i):
            if (i%x) != 0:
                ctr += 1
                break
            else:
                break
            

    return ctr

print(count_primes(10))
#I get 4
print(count_primes(100))
#I get 49
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic of how you find your prime numbers?

Comment: In your second `for` loop, you only iterate only once as you break it no matter what

Comment: What do you see when you add some print(i) and print(x) statements inside your for-loop? Did you even try this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the logic is as follows - for every number you just check if it is divisible by 2 and break. Let's simulate for `i=9`. Then for `x=2`, `(9 %2)!=0` but 9 is not prime but is counted as one. Check the following code -

```
def isPrime(n):
    if not isinstance(n, int):
       raise ValueError('n must be integer')
    if n <= 0:
       raise ValueError('n is negative or zero')
    if n==1: return False
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n %  i == 0:
           return False
    return True


def countPrime(n):
    ctr = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
         if isPrime(i):
            ctr += 1
    return ctr
```

Disclaimer - there are more efficient ways to check if a number is prime

Comment: Note that your solution returns `True` for `isPrime(1)`